# GStreamer h264 decode acceleration

Tags: gpu, gstreamer, hardware-acceleration

My C# program uses `GStreamer` library to obtain frames from IP cameras. The pipe scheme is this:

> rtsp source > rtp h264 depay > decodebin > appsink

The problem is that `decodebin` uses CPU only, so when I connect to like a dozen cameras, the CPU overloads.

The question is: is there any way to make `GSrteamer` use some kind of GPU acceleration?

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MoralesBatovski have you used GStreamer already? the questions about GStreamer are usually asked in a form of gst-launch (something similar is in the question in quote).. which is scripting like language .. the question is very clear to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, but you have to use vaapi which may have to be compiled or installed.

Check this git repo .. [README](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-vaapi/tree/README?h=1.8)

After installing you will do something like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc ! rtph264depay ! vaapidecode ! .. whatever
```

I hope it will work this way as I never tried that before

HTH